# Grails: how to restrict fetching of linked elements to user?

Tags: security, grails, spring-security

Currently we are restricting the access of (sub- or linked)elements through explicitly define the criteria while using `list()` with hibernate criteria.

It would be nice, if the domain objects knows the user-context and automatically restricts the access to linked objects, which the user is able to receive. Otherwise there might be a security issue when getting non-allowed objects through sub-objects for example during `JSON` rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce design that force you to query objects through services. Then let service augment your query with additional security constraints. Domain object is doing lot of stuff already, adding security context is possible but will kick your team sooner or later.

Comment: Thanks for that hint. Cant this be done with database-views? (http://www.mscharhag.com/2014/01/using-database-views-in-grails.html) Implementing the security in a service is probably not much more efficient and "failsave" than in a controller?!